Nao consigo fazer a criacao do npx create-react-app, pois da o mesmo erro, ja tentei reinstalar e nao funcionou
Erro na criacao do npx create-react-app
Ja tentei --force, ja tentei mudanca de versao, entre outros e eh sempre o mesmo erro.

https://dev.to/ag2byte/create-react-app-is-officially-dead-h7o

Uma solução é seguir pela linha dos frameworks sugeridos pela documentação: https://react.dev/learn/start-a-new-react-project --- Next.js: npx create-next-app@latest ou Remix: npx create-remix ou Gatsby: npx create-gatsby. Se for criar aplicativos a sugestão é o Expo: npx create-expo-app.
